# PostgreSQL cannot generate uuid but uuid-ossp extension is installed?

Tags: postgresql

postgresql11-server-11.8_2

When I try to add a new client in idempiere I get the following error message:

```
    idempiere Version=7.1.0.202008290007

    Initial Client Setup Process

Do you want to start the Process?

** org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Where: PL/pgSQL function generate_uuid() line 3 at RETURN
```

This usually indicates that the uuid extension is missing from the database.  But this is not the case.

```
[root@accounting-2 ~ (master)]# sudo -u postgres psql --dbname=idempiere
psql (11.8)
Type "help" for help.

idempiere=# \dx
                            List of installed extensions
   Name    | Version |   Schema   |                   Description                   
-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 uuid-ossp | 1.1     | public     | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)
```

What is causing this?  How is it fixed?

Comment: Have  tried running `generate_uuid()`  and/or  `uuid_generate_v4()` in  `psql` to see if they work? If they do then it is something in  "Initial Client Setup Process". I would tail the Postgres log when you run the process to see what is being sent to the server.

Comment: What does `select * from pg_extension` give you in the idempiere client? And does `select uuid_generate();` work in psql?

Answer (score 1):

The output of \dx in my postgres looks like this:

```
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 uuid-ossp | 1.1     | adempiere  | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)
```

In your case it shows uuid-ossp installed in the public schema, while in my case is installed in adempiere schema.

Please try the following command in your idempiere database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"
```